# Ajax: Function specified in route is not called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a button that when you click it, it will show a confirmation box. If the user clicks 'ok', the word 'reached' would display inside of the div named 'EventData'.

So far the confirmation box shows when I click the button but 'EventData' won't show the word 'reached' when I confirm it.

*the 'event_id' has a value

I think the problem is with the url part where it won't go in the function

Route:

```
Route::post('/ArchiveEventPosts','AdminController@ArchiveEventposts')->name('ArchiveEventposts');
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive', function() {

    var event_id = $(this).attr('event_id');

    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to archive this record?");

    if (x) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route("ArchiveEventposts") }}',
            data: {
                event_id: event_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#EventData').html(data);
                alert('Record Archived');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Function in the controller:

```
public function ArchiveEventposts(Request $request)
{
   echo 'Reached';
}
```

Comment: What's the status code? I see that you aren't passing the CSRF token for `POST` request on a web route. Can you paste the console output for the request?

Comment: @Rehmat Sorry but I honestly don't know what your talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to change the way your route is assigned. What you are doing is assigning a plain string to the URL with a single quotation mark. Try like this:

```
var archiveEventpostsRoute = "{{ route('ArchiveEventposts') }}";
```

and below

```
url: archiveEventpostsRoute,
```

Also, make sure that your controller is returning the proper data, as stated in the other answer:

```
public function ArchiveEventposts(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["message" => "Reached"]);
}
```

Comment: @JohnClyde Can you please add `alert(archiveEventpostsRoute)` immediately after creating it to confirm that is assigning the proper route

Comment: yep it shows the path :

http://localhost:8000/ArchiveEventPosts

Comment: @JohnClyde if you manually go to that link you just posted (open in the browser), does it show something like `message => Reached` in the form of JSON?

Comment: I went to the link and it showed:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, it expects POST, correct. I guess try changing the route to accept GET instead of POST temporarily to see what's the problem. It really should work as-is.

Comment: If now changing method to `method: "GET"`, doesn't work, I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: will just wait for more answers. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: @JohnClyde Can you put it live somewhere to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is not returning any data; it's simply printing the word "Reached".

You'll need to change the function to something like this:

```
public function ArchiveEventposts(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["message" => "Reached"]);
}
```

Comment: The solution is probably a combination of your and my answer.